# run C++ UDF in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to find a way to run C++ UDF in Spark. So far I can only find the way to run Java UDF and cannot find anything about running C++ UDF.

Anyone knows how to do it in Spark (either Scala or PySpark)?

Answer (score 0):

C++ is not supported as as a guest language so you cannot write C++ UDF. What you can do is to call you C++ code from Scala or Python within support UDF.

**In Scala** you can use [Java Native Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html). Intefaced code has to be thread safe.

**In Python** you can write a [C/C++ Extension](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html), [Swig inteface](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Python.html) or [Cython](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html). Workers are isolated so thread safety is not required.